# MariaDB 10.1.33 keeps crashing

Tags: mariadb

I have a standard master/multiple slave set up on CentOS 7 running on EC2.

I actually have three identical slaves (all spawned off the same AMI), but only one is crashing about once a day.  I've posted the dump from error.log below, as well as the query log referencing the connection ID in the error dump.

I've tried looking at the MariaDB docs, but all it points to is resolve_stack_dump but no real help on trying to figure it out from there.

The slave that is crashing is running many batch-like queries, but according to the dump logs, the last connection id is never one of the connections running queries.

For this slave, I have the system turn off slave updates (SQL_THREAD), run queries for 15 minutes, stop the queries, start the slave until caught up, stop the slave updates, and restart the queries. Repeat.   This code has been working pretty much non-stop/crash-free for years now when I had a colo set up before I moved to AWS.

My other two cloned slaves only run the replication queries as a hot-spare of the master (which I've never needed to use).  Those servers never crash.

thanks.

Error.log crash dump:

> 180618 13:12:46 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 11 ; This could be because
>   you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary or one of the
>   libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built, or
>   misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning
>   hardware.
>
> To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs
>
> We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
>   diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, something is
>   definitely wrong and this may fail.
>
> Server version: 10.1.33-MariaDB 
>   
> key_buffer_size=268431360
>   read_buffer_size=268431360 
>   max_used_connections=30 
>   max_threads=42
>   thread_count=11 
>   It is possible that mysqld could use up to
>   key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads =
>   22282919 K  bytes of memory Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some
>   variables in the equation.
>
> Thread pointer: 0x7f4209f1c008 Attempting backtrace. You can use the
>   following information to find out where mysqld died. If you see no
>   messages after this, something went terribly wrong... stack_bottom =
>   0x7f4348db90b0 thread_stack 0x48400
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x55c19a7be10e]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x305)[0x55c19a2e1295]
>   sigaction.c:0(__restore_rt)[0x7f4348a835e0]
>   sql/sql_class.h:3406(sql_set_variables(THD*, List*,
>   bool))[0x55c19a0d2ecd]
>
>   sql/sql_list.h:179(base_list::empty())[0x55c19a14bcb8]
>
>   sql/sql_parse.cc:2007(dispatch_command(enum_server_command, THD*,
>   char*, unsigned int))[0x55c19a15e85a]
>   sql/sql_parse.cc:1122(do_command(THD*))[0x55c19a160f37]
>   sql/sql_connect.cc:1330(do_handle_one_connection(THD*))[0x55c19a22d6da]
>   sql/sql_connect.cc:1244(handle_one_connection)[0x55c19a22d880]
>   pthread_create.c:0(start_thread)[0x7f4348a7be25]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f4346e1f34d]
>   
>   Trying to get some variables.
>  Some pointers may be invalid and cause
>   the dump to abort. 
> Query (0x0): Connection ID (thread ID): 15894
>   Status: NOT_KILLED
>   
>   Optimizer switch:
>   index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=off,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=off

Query Log for connection ID:

> 180618 13:11:01
>   15894 Connect   ****@piper**** as anonymous on
>                   15894 Query     show status
>                   15894 Prepare   show full processlist /* m6clone1 */
>
>                   15894 Execute   show full processlist /* m6clone1 */
>                   15894 Close stmt
>                   15894 Query     show slave status
>                   15894 Query     show variables
>                   15894 Quit

Comment: Sure smells like a hardware error.  If you can't convince AWS of that, then convince them to move the slave to different hardware.  (Maybe upgrade to a beefier instance, wait a while, then downgrade.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll give the upgrade idea a shot for a few days.

Comment: Well, that seemed to have done it.  I moved from r4.large to r4.xlarge doubling memory and number of processors, and MariaDB hasn't crashed in two days and counting.   It will cost me double, but a stable platform is worth it. I guess I assumed that a hardware error wouldn't crash the database like this and I'd get some warnings like out of memory or too many connections, etc (like I've seen every other time!).   Thanks.

Comment: The clues:  (*) Only one slave was having the problem; (*) Sig 11 is rather bad crash.